# Is it advisable to use CSS frameworks?

Tags: css, frameworks

I'm an average web developer. Just want to find out if it's advisable to use CSS frameworks such as the **[960 framework](http://960.gs/)**. if anyone has, what are the pros and cons of using it.
thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It depends on what you will use it for. It will probably speed up your css development if you use it, but you will lose a bit of flexibility.

It is actually the same for all of those 'frameworks', not only for css...

If you decide to work with a css framework, I recommend reading [this article](http://nettuts.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/which-css-grid-framework-should-you-use-for-web-design/)

Comment: Why do you lose flexibility?  Is it because each framework uses some pre-defined layout that you build on top of?  I'm curious, if this is obvious I apologize in advance. This is something I'm new to, but I'm very interested in.

Comment: yup, it is because of that. For example, documents created with the 960 framework mentioned above will always have a width of 960 px.

Comment: what about the "blueprint framework". is it the same concept as the 960 grid?

Comment: Yes, it is the same concept... Actually it is just a (number of) .css file(s) which you can use to create your website + an explanation on how to use these css files.

Answer (score 3):

There's two widely adopted options: [960](http://960.gs) and [blueprint](http://www.blueprintcss.org/). Both rely on a [grid-based layout](http://csswizardry.com/typogridphy/) system. Both include a [CSS reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) as well.

The advantage here is obviously that you get more a consistent layout across multiple browsers and if you test on Firefox for example you have a better chance that it looks the same on IE. Because these frameworks are grid based, your layout is also a lot cleaner and well-aligned. Both have horizontal alignment but vertical alignment or vertical rhythm is only supported in Blueprint.

The downside is that it may be overkill for your layout. If you want a simple three column layout then you could just go for  a CSS reset plus a three column layout template.

Personally I have found that using these frameworks gives me a lot of creative expression and I have done a lot more with my layouts after adopting these frameworks than I ever did before because of cross-browser CSS hackery. I use Blueprint because I find it very intuitive but 960 Grid System has also gotten great reviews.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, as a starting point, provided you're ready to strip out the stuff that's irrelevant to you, and are happy making changes to it. It's a great way to get started on a layout/design, but it's no use if you then write a stylesheet that overrides the rules in the framework's CSS. Be ready to adjust it to suit what you're working on.

As an aside, I quite like [bluetrip](http://bluetrip.org/), which:

> combine[s] the best of Blueprint,
>   Tripoli (hence the name), Hartija's
>   print stylesheet, 960.gs's simplicity,
>   and Element's icons